# PostgreSQL 11.16 cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a PostgreSQL database running on an Azure machine. When I try to create a table on a database, I get an error "cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction". The SQL query is being executed by a python script using a sqlalchemy engine. But I tried a similar query in PGAdmin installed on my machine and I get the same error. And I noticed that I do not have this issue if I connect to the database from a colleague's machine.

After further research, I found that if I execute `SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();` in my PGAdmin, it returns true. And false on my colleague's machine.

Let me know if there is any way to correct this

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same database? As the same user?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT pg_is_in_recovery()  - returned true =  Database has only Read Acces

can you check your permission?

you can check  postgresql.conf file and atribute default_transaction_read_only

or try this:

```
begin;
set transaction read write;
alter database exercises set default_transaction_read_only = off;
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that our posgtresql machine is a HA machine, and that I was connecting to an IP address rather than the domain.